# Java Servlet extend another Servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

The `init` method in most (all) of my servlets is similar. Mostly initializing a `DataSource`

I am thinking of creating a `BaseServlet` having a protected `DataSource` and the `init` method implemented and all other servlets extend this `BaseServlet`.

Any Gotchas I should be wary of?

Comment: You can consider declaring your resource requirement in the deployment descriptor rather than creating a base servlet. I think that would be a cleaner approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current approach:

1. Every Servlet extending `BaseServlet` will create its own datasource as the `init()` method will be called multiple times.
2. I assume this is not what you want to accomplish and you are looking for a single datasource to be used across all the Servlets.

Assuming above is true, I would suggest following

1. Wrap your datasource in a singleton class. This will make sure that datasource initialized only once. Use [eager initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Eager_initialization) to make sure the Datasource is initalized at the class load itself
2. Use this class to get the datasource/connections in your servlet class.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need initialize the Database related stuff, you can put that into ServletContext, I am not a fun of so many class inheritance.

nowadays, seems we don't just start from servlet, why not choose a framework?